# How to have colored headers in Semantic-UI modals?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I tried having a header with an inverted color but that did not change anything.

I also tried changing the header to a segmented control but that still leaves a white gap at the top and also has round corners

Comment: Please provide the code you are having trouble with, and more detail to the question. As is, it's much too vague to answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently available in semantic-ui. You may want to set a different color by using a custom css code:

```js
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

```css
.ui.modal > .header{
  background-color: gold !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    This is a modal with custom header background
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="description">
      A description can appear on the right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui button">OK</div>
  </div>
</div>
```